# Language recognition in Java

Tags: java, open-source, nlp

Is there any language recognition open-source for Java? Found only for c/c++.

**UPD:**

I`m talking about human text language. Example:

Input: My name is John.
Output: English.

Input: Ich heisse John.
Output: German.

Input: Меня зовут Джон.
Output: Russian.

Comment: Please tell us what sort of software you want.  Should it be a formal automaton, recognizing whether a string is in a particular formal language?  Should it tell what human language a text is in?  Tell what language some source code is written in?  Tell what language some executable might have been written in?  Recognize whether sounds are words or just noises?  Recognize what language people are talking in?

Comment: Bit picky, but had to -1 since no research effort is shown... it is a good question though, so I favourited it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See what you think of the version in [Apache Tika](http://lucene.apache.org/tika/). This assumes that you want to find out what language text is in, as opposed to wanting to build a parser for a programming language.

Comment: perhaps provide a link to Tika

Answer (score 3):

Textcat http://textcat.sourceforge.net/ doesn't have Russian but it does handle the following:

- albanian

  danish

  dutch

  english

  finnish

  french

  german

  hungarian

  italian

  norwegian

  polish

  slovakian

  slovenian

  spanish

  swedish

Answer (score 1):

There is [Language Detection API](http://detectlanguage.com) which accepts text via HTTP POST and returns JSON with detected languages and scores. It can be used from Java or any other programming language.

Answer (score 0):

I think [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) is pretty much standard.

Comment: One of us is confused. I thought he wanted a way to tell if text was in Chinese or Japanese, and you think he wants to make a parser! We'll see.

Comment: @bmargulies - it could not be inferred from the question, so both answers make sense.