# Check String content language in java

Tags: string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Language recognition in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310536/language-recognition-in-java)

I need to check the language of data present in the string. Pls some one help on this.

for Ex:

```
String str ="Sample";
```

str string consist of english language data.

```
String str1 = "عينة";
```

str string consist of arabic language data.

Comment: You may be able to make some determination about what character set is being used, but determining the language will not be possible.  For instance, many words (maybe not sample) are the same in English, French, Spanish, etc...

Answer (score 0):

There are external libraries available.

[Here is one of them](http://code.google.com/p/language-detection/)