# Converting a string from a language to another using unicode

Tags: java, eclipse, unicode

One approach is using the info we know about language ranges. For example,
unicode range 30A0–30FF represents Japanese Katakana characters, so if your string
consists of characters within that range, you could make an educated guess that it's
Japanese and work accordingly.

This requires knowing how to handle unicode language pages in java

Any help please

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Formulate a real question and tell us what you have tried, or what exactly you don't understand.

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310536/language-recognition-in-java if you haven't found it already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java `char` is 16 bit unicode. Just get a string and go parsing its characters:

```
String string = getString(); // returns the string you will parse
boolean japaneseChars = true;
for (ii=0; ii<string.length; ii++) {
    char character = string.charAt(ii);
    if (!(character >= 0x30A0 && character<= 0x30FF)) {
         japaneseChars = false;
    }
}
```